# Why are fields that are not included on a form not persisted between OnGet and OnPost?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor-pages, .net-5

When we post changes from the form, fields not explicitly included in the form are being cleared.

We noticed this specifically when we added a new column, attribute on the Model, but did not include it in the edit form. The values were cleared in the database.

When we inspect the entity OnGet, the Record attributes have the expected values.

OnPost, before the Record is sent to the context for updating, the values for the attributes excluded from the form have been cleared.

When we add those attributes to the form, hidden or visible doesn't matter, the values are preserved.

How do we correct this without including those properties on the form?

Sample model

```
    public class Record 
    {
        Id int { get; set; }
        Name string { get; set; }
        Notes string { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(Region))]
        RegionId int { get; set; }
        Region RelatedRegion { get; set; }
    }
```

We have an interface for accessing the data

```
    public interface IRecordAccessor
    {
        public Task<Record> UpdateRecord(Record updatedRecord);
        public Task<Record> GetRecord(int recordId);
        public Task<int> Commit();
    }

    public class RecordAcessor : IRecordAccessor 
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;
  
        public RecordAccessor(AppDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<Record> UpdateRecord(Record updatedRecord)
        {
            _context.Entry(updatedRecord).State = EntityState.Modified;
            return updatedRecord;
        }

        public async Task<Record> GetRecord(int recordId)
        {
            return await _context.Records.FirstOrDefaultAsync( r => r.Id == recordId );
                      
        }

        public async Task<int> Commit()
        {
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
     }
```

Excerpt from PageModel

```
    private readonly IRecordAccessor _recordAccessor;

    [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true )]
    public Record editRecord { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int recordId)
    {
        editRecord = await _recordAccessor.GetRecord(recordId);

        return Page();        
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        if(editRecord.Id > 0)
        {
            await _recordAccessor.UpdateRecord(editRecord);
        }
        else 
        {
            // new record, add it
        }

        await _recordAccessor.Commit();

        return RedirectToPage("/Edit", new { recordId = editRecord.Id });
    }
```

**Edit 2021-05-13 19:52 UTC**
Changed title and explanation of issue to better reflect the actual issue.

Comment: Posting one and the same question twice won't help getting an answer. Also you can remove `entity-framework-core` tag as the issue is purely in view - controller communication, or view data binging etc.

Comment: `_context.Entry(updatedRecord).State = EntityState.Modified;` that's what forces EF to update all fields. Don't do that. Just update record's properties and EF will find difference.

Comment: @Ivan Stoev Thank you, I was interrupted when posting and didn't delete the other post. I probably should have just edited it in retrospect.

Comment: @Svyatoslav Danyliv thank you, but that's not it. When I remove that the record does not update at all. I thought the entity was tracked when accessed. Is it a problem with using an interface?

Comment: You have to change property of the the record which you have to update and it should be tracked entity.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv, that's as I understand it. `_context.Entity.FirstOrDefaultAsync(...)` retrieves a tracked entity. Edits via a form should be tracked and I should be able to commit the changes with `_context.SaveChangesAsync()`. 
It doesn't see to work that way though. Obviously I've done something tragically wrong.

Comment: Check that DI configured to have Scoped lifetime for DbContext.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv as far as I understand, the lifetime is Scoped when using `services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(
        options => options.UseSqlServer("name=ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"));` which is how I initialize the DbContext.

Inspecting the Entity on Post, before it is sent to the DbContext, I can see that the values are not being persisted. 
`OnGet => Record.RegionId == 1;`, `OnPost => Record.RegionId == 0;`

It sounds like @IvanStoev is correct, it's an MVC issue. I still don't know how to solve it though.